# what is CocosBuilder .ccbi file

Tags: xml, cocos2d-iphone, cocosbuilder

When using CocosBuilder, it generates both .ccb file and .ccbi file. In project you use .ccbi file instead of .ccb file. I have a couple question on these, 
1, what is .ccbi file
2, why using .ccbi file instead of .ccb file? 
Thanks in advance for your answers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CCB files are simple Plist-files with a ccb extension. It is ***human readable*** (text/xml) and you can easily edit it manually if required. For example, I sometimes will generate several scenes based on one ccb file using a simple script. The format is [well documented](https://github.com/cocos2d/CocosBuilder/blob/master/Documentation/X3.%20CCB%20File%20Format.md) on CocosBuilder github page.

One distinction, is that Sticky Notes which are meant to be displayed in CocosBuidler are only found in CCB files.

CCBi is a **binary format** meant **for publishing**.

> It is a binary file format designed to be as compact as possible and
>   very quick to load.

The binary format is also [documented by CocosBuilder](https://github.com/cocos2d/CocosBuilder/blob/master/Documentation/X4.%20CCBi%20File%20Format.md).

Comment: with that said, using ccbi file is faster than ccb file? Thanks for the answer, very helpful.

Comment: @ppl can u help me to load .ccbi file by CCBReader because i am trying to load that file but its not at all working. Its working in debug mode but in release mode its returning nil.