# Cocos 2D GUI & Xcode 5

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I have an `iOS game` app that was created in `Cocos 2D` & `Box 2D` by an outside developer where I need to make some minor `UI` modifications (nudging platforms, item positions, etc.).

Normally, to get a visual view of the app in previous versions of `Xcode`, you would go to the `.xib` file. In Xcode 5 this is supposedly replaced with `main.storyboard`. Though I can build & run my project in the simulator or as an .iap file on my device, I cannot figure out how to make corrections to graphics (re positioning) as I would normally do. The `main.storyboard` file doesn't exist in my project.

Current file extensions represented:

```
.h, .mm, .cpp, .cmake, .pch
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will need some time to get into cocos2d. The best thing is to begin in the documentation of codos2d: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/

Answer (score 1):

Most cocos2d apps position "graphics" in code. Storyboard and xib files are not used at all for visual layout of cocos2d elements (nodes).

At best you'll find ccb or ccbi files which would indicate that CocosBuilder was used to design the scene's layouts. If there are no such files, you have to look into and modify the code.

Answer (score -1):

If it was created in cocos2d/box2d, there are any number of ways that the presentation could have been created.  Usually these don't involve storyboard/.xib files for cocos2d/box2d.

All the files you listed are standard code files; I don't see any graphics files (.png, .pvr, etc.) or physics editor files (.pes) in your list, or CocosBuilder files ([ccb/ccbi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16881582/what-is-cocosbuilder-ccbi-file)).   There are probably more file extensions in your project that you may want to find.  You could potentially list out all the file extensions in your project, and maybe somebody on SO will be able to help you identify the tool or tweak the code by posting it.

However, I think the best option is to find a developer familiar with these technologies, let them take a look at the code, and get you back on track.

You may type a lot into SO and wait a long time for an answer to something a good developer could find for you in a few hours. If this is an academic (no commercial project), they may do it for free.  Or for a nominal fee for a commercial project.  Or for good will.  Or the fun of it.  etc.